# Error running cron job `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, capistrano3, whenever, rvm-capistrano

I have deployed application using Capistrano 3. I keep on getting following error.

```
`require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

Here is the cron tab list

```
PATH=/home/deploy/magnificent/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/deploy/magnificent/releases/20150830045359 && bin/rails runner -e production '\''Document.process_pending'\'' >> log/cron_standard.log 2>> log/cron_error.log'
```

and **schedule.rb**

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
set :output, { error: 'log/cron_error.log', standard: 'log/cron_standard.log'}

every 1.minutes do
  runner 'Document.process_pending'
end
```

Please note here that all the gems are installed in `default` gemset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Please note here that all the gems are installed in default gemset

I had 3 gemsets available in production. Rails is using `default` one where all required gems are installed.

As can be seen in the crontab list, crontab is also looking path in `global` gemset directory as well.

So I just selected `global` gemset and install `bundler`

```
$ rvm gemset use global
$ gem install bundler
```

These steps fixed the issue.

Comment: when attempting to issue the first step, i get "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work"

Comment: I did the same thing and it solved my problem except it included ```rvm gemset create global``` first. Then it reinstalled all of my gems and my app was running perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
rvm cron setup
```